# JAX-RS web service in WSO2 ESB'a sample axis server

Tags: web-services, rest, jax-rs, wso2, wso2-esb

I wanted to know if we can create and host JAX-RS web service in WSO2ESB's sample axis2 server.

If yes can someone be kind enough to give me a link to a working example.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it is  possible,build the service and deploy that to sample axis2Server\repository\services folder

Comment: well can you give me a link to a working example??
also http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/ says "axis2 is for soap and wsdl"....so i m again confused...